# Incorrect Nuget project referencing issue on VSTS however no issue locally

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, azure-pipelines

- I have two **.NET Standard 1.4** [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) projects

  1. Ninja.Abstractions
  2. Ninja.Domain
- **Ninja.Domain** references **Ninja.Abstraction**.
- **GeneratePackageOnBuild** is `true` for both projects
- They both have code below in ***.csproj** file

> ```
>    <PropertyGroup>
>       <BuildNumber Condition=" '$(BuildNumber)' == '' ">0.0.0</BuildNumber>
>       <VersionPrefix>$(BuildNumber)</VersionPrefix>
>       <VersionSuffix Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">dev</VersionSuffix>
>     </PropertyGroup>
> ```

- When I compile the project, I do not receive error message and everything looks fine.

> *On [vsts](/questions/tagged/vsts) I delete the 3rd project which is called **Ninja.Host**, so please ignore that project since it is just for demonstration purposes.*

- On [vsts](/questions/tagged/vsts) I only do **Restore** and **Build** not **Pack** nor **Publish**.
- I push the `BuildNumber` value via arguments as `/p:BuildNumber=$(Build.BuildNumber)` for **Build** task
  [image: vsts tasks]
- I do copy `**/*.nupkg` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\nuget` directory via **Copy Task**
- When I queue the build on [vsts](/questions/tagged/vsts) I get warning below.
  [image: vsts build log]

  ```
  2017-08-07T03:23:50.2098321Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Domain\Ninja.Domain.csproj --configuration release /p:BuildNumber=1.0.353
  2017-08-07T03:23:50.3518364Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
  2017-08-07T03:23:50.3518364Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  2017-08-07T03:23:50.3518364Z 
  2017-08-07T03:23:51.9897194Z   Ninja.Abstractions -> d:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Abstractions\bin\release\netstandard1.4\Ninja.Abstractions.dll
  2017-08-07T03:23:52.1097005Z   Successfully created package 'd:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Abstractions\bin\release\Ninja.Abstractions.1.0.353.nupkg'.
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.6697753Z   Ninja.Domain -> d:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Domain\bin\release\netstandard1.4\Ninja.Domain.dll
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.7253932Z   Successfully created package 'd:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Domain\bin\release\Ninja.Domain.1.0.353.nupkg'.
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.7267788Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(104,5): warning : Issue found with package 'Ninja.Domain'. [d:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Domain\Ninja.Domain.csproj]
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.7277784Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(104,5): warning : Issue: Prerelease dependency in stable package. [d:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Domain\Ninja.Domain.csproj]
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.7277784Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(104,5): warning : Description: A stable release of a package should not have a prerelease dependency. [d:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Domain\Ninja.Domain.csproj]
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.7277784Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(104,5): warning : Solution: Either modify the version spec of dependency "Ninja.Abstractions [0.0.0-dev, )" or update the version field in the nuspec. [d:\a\1\s\src\Ninja.Domain\Ninja.Domain.csproj]
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.7297813Z 
  2017-08-07T03:23:53.7307788Z Build succeeded.
  ```
- Downloaded artifacts and have 2 files which has **Ninja.Abstractions.1.0.353.nupkg** and **Ninja.Domain.1.0.353.nupkg**
- Opened **Ninja.Abstractions.nuspec** which is in **Ninja.Abstractions.1.0.353.nupkg**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
      <id>Ninja.Abstractions</id>
      <version>1.0.353</version>
      <authors>Ninja.Abstractions</authors>
      <owners>Ninja.Abstractions</owners>
      <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
      <description>Package Description</description>
      <dependencies>
        <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.4">
          <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        </group>
      </dependencies>
    </metadata>
  </package>
  ```
- Opened **Ninja.Domain.nuspec** which is in **Ninja.Domain.1.0.353.nupkg**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
      <id>Ninja.Domain</id>
      <version>1.0.353</version>
      <authors>Ninja.Domain</authors>
      <owners>Ninja.Domain</owners>
      <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
      <description>Package Description</description>
      <dependencies>
        <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.4">
          <dependency id="Ninja.Abstractions" version="0.0.0-dev" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
          <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        </group>
      </dependencies>
    </metadata>
  </package>
  ```

As you can see it has `<dependency id="Ninja.Abstractions" version="0.0.0-dev" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />` which should be `<dependency id="Ninja.Abstractions" version="1.0.353" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />` and this behaviour does not apply when I build it locally.  In Visual Studio 2017 it builds the way it is suppose to do with the correct dependency information.

> *I was thinking about adding explicit **nuspec** file but it will force me to track references manually which is not something I would like to do.*

I appreciate any afford to help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to pass `/p:BuildNumber=$(Build.BuildNumber)` to `dotnet restore` since the NuGet dependency package versions are locked at restore time and written out to the `obj\project.assets.json` file. See [this similar issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4337) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you! It did pass the version number and dependency version became `1.0.353-dev` which means it is getting called as **Debug** configuration. _(which is a concern but not in my case)_

I called it with `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)` it didn't work and I changed it to `/p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration)` and it worked.

So basically I needed to add `/p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) /p:BuildNumber=$(Build.BuildNumber)` to `dotnet restore`

You saved my day, thank you again!